# RegEx of odd length binary strings with no '11'

Tags: regular-expressions

I am quite new to Regular Expressions, and I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Design a regular expression that accepts the language of all binary strings which their length is odd with no occurrences of 11.

At first, this is what I have:
`(0(00) * 1 + 1(00) * 0) * (0 + 1)`

However, I am told that this is wrong. A quick Google Search and I got this as regex for binary strings excluding '11':

`(0 + 10) * 0 *`

Please, why is my answer wrong, what is the right answer and how to get it?

Comment: One thing that you can do for problems like these (which may be overkill for this particular problem) is to create two DFAs: $M_1$ which accepts all odd length binary strings and $M_2$ which accepts all binary strings with no 11. These DFAs are quite easy to construct. And then, since DFAs are closed under union, you can systematically combine the two DFAs with a simple process. Finally, you can use an additional algorithm to systematically [convert this](https://shorturl.at/deBG3) DFA to a regular expression. Hope this can help a little bit.

Comment: @codeing_monkey Thanks. This is my adjusted answer: ((0(10)*) | 1)((01)* | (00)(10)*)*

Comment: = ((0(10)*) U 1)((01)* U (00)(10)*)*